# Reset a scriplet variable on refresh

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

I have a table and I want the lines to be numbered.

In my jsp, I have something like that:

```
<%! int i = 0; %> 
 <c:forEach items="${clients}" var="client">  
    <tr>  
       <td align="center"><%= ++i %></td>  
       <td><c:out value="${client.nomPrenom}"/></td>  
....
```

My problem is when I refresh the page, variable i is not reset to 0. It continues to ++

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that using jstl as follows ,  as scriplets are not advised over decades

```
<c:forEach items="${clients}" var="client" varStatus="loop">  
    <tr>  
       <td align="center"><c:out value="${loop.index}" /></td>  
       <td><c:out value="${client.nomPrenom}"/></td>  
    </tr>
</ c:forEach>
```

see [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) to learn more on using the jstl and EL

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer.
I now scriplet are very bad, but it is also true that I don't know how to avoid them. I think your link will be very helpfull for me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSP is translated to servlet by server container. Every time you refresh your page `_jspService` is called.

Translation of JSP to servlet code :

```
public class HelloWorld2$jsp extends HttpJspBase {
        //code declare inside <%! %> method goes here
        public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)

        {
            // code declare inside <% %> method goes here

        }
    }
```

Instead of

```
<%! int i = 0; %>
```

Use Below Code:

```
 <% int i = 0; %>
```